# Async call works on console but not on webapi

Tags: c#, firebase, asp.net-web-api, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I need to connect to Firebase from a C# WebApi.

For this I have made a Class Library which is the one who connects to Firebase and retrieve the information.

When I call this Class Library from a Console application, everything runs smoothly, but when I try to run it from a WebApi using Postman it starts to get async problems. Specifically DeadLock is happening.

I'm using FirebaseDatabase.net nugget as Firebase client.

EDIT

```
private async Task<string> LoginAsync()
    {
        var FirebaseApiKey = "XXXXXXXX";
        var authProvider = new FirebaseAuthProvider(new FirebaseConfig(FirebaseApiKey));
        var auth = await authProvider.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync("myemail@mail.com", "mypassword");
        return auth.FirebaseToken;
    }

    public FirebaseClient getClient()
    {
        if (client == null)
        {
            client = new FirebaseClient("https://approach-197117.firebaseio.com", new FirebaseOptions
            {
                AuthTokenAsyncFactory = LoginAsync
            });
        }
        return client;
    }

    public static async Task<Dictionary<string, Location>> Run()
    {
        FirebaseConnect firebaseConnect = new FirebaseConnect().getInstance();
        var firebase = firebaseConnect.getClient();
        var list = await firebase.Child("Location").OnceSingleAsync<Dictionary<string, Location>>();
        return list;
    }
```

The problem comes that when I try to do a OnceSingleAsync asking for Location, the call works on a console app but doesn't work on a webapi call

Comment: Without looking at your code it's not possible to guess what's wrong with your code. So you need to share the code

Comment: Provide the code snippets how are you using it in Console and WebAPI, as such nothing seems to be wrong with your code

Comment: It seems to be that the Nugget I was using to get the Firebase Token is having Deadlocks as a bug. There is nothing to do here. Thank you for your help!